# Twitter Bootstrap and Chosen jQuery Plugin not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, forms, jquery-chosen

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap + Chosen.

I'm calling Chosen for a select, but it doesn't work (as in, it uses the Twitter Bootstrap styling) until you click on a link in the page that grabs another page (an order form) via Ajax & displays it via Fancybox; this page also uses Chosen. After clicking that, Chosen is applied to the select correctly.

The head sections of the pages look identical; jQuery is being called first, other plugins for jQuery (UI for sliders) work fine. The path to Chosen is correct. Removing Bootstrap to test didn't help (it just showed unstyled until the order page was grabbed.

Comment: Is it only the styling, or it doesn't work ? Have you included the css ?

Answer (score 7):

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and Chosen beautiful drop down from long time. I never face such problems. You might inserted chosen CSS before bootstrap CSS or missing / overwrite styles. Here is the full working code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- scale the devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <!-- include bootstrap css files -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />

        <title>Twitter Bootstrap + Choosen</title>

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->        

        <!-- includ jquery and bootstrap script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

        <!-- choosen -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/chosen/chosen.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() { 
            // chosen select
            $("form select").chosen({no_results_text: "No results matched"});
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- container -->
        <div class="container">

            <!-- content -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <!-- user form -->
                    <form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label for="group_id" class="control-label">User Group : </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select name="group_id" id="group_id" class="input-xlarge">
                                    <option value="">select...</option>
                                    <option value="1">Administrator</option>
                                    <option value="3"selected="selected">Users</option>
                                    <option value="4">Random</option>
                                    <option value="5">Super New</option>
                                    <option value="6">Famous</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- // end form -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- // end content -->

        </div>
        <!-- // end container -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is image attachment/screenshot (as it is)

[image: Twitter Bootstrap + Chosen jQuery Plugin]

Hope this helps. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

have you Called `$('select').Chosen()` when the document is ready?

```
$(document).ready(function,{

     $('select').Chosen();

});
```